# Database connectivity error in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have lost connectivity using Visual Studio 2012 database...
when i try to reconnect and run the application then here us the Exception [image]

NOTE: The previous file was deleted mistakenly, and trying to attach the new one it says it already exist? 
what is the Solution?

Comment: Which database system are you connecting your MSVC 2012 IDE with? is it MSDN, Sqllite or Mysql db?

Answer (score 2):

What kind of database are you running? Specify:

If you have SQLEXPRESS Database:
First you need to change your Data Source name like this.

```
"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0" to "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS"
```

To connect to your local SQL Server instance, issue the following string:

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=C:\MyFolder\MyDataFile.mdf;Database=dbname Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

To connect to your local SQL Server instance with a database file located in a data directory, issue the following string:

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

To connect to LocalDB Automatic Instance, issue the following string:

```
Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;
```

To connect to LocalDB Automatic Instance with a specific data, issue the following string:

```
Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true; AttachDbFileName=C:\MyFolder\MyData.mdf;
```

To connect to LocalDB named Instance, issue the following string:

```
Server=(localdb)\MyInstance;Integrated Security=true;
```

You need to get a string that matches your specific DB exactly, for it to connect.

Answer (score 0):

In you connection string just add the 'database='. This prevents SQL server to create the auto-named database.

Comment: can u explain please ? this is the connection string where i have to put it ?

Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\Talah\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\ACMS.mdf';Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

Comment: in the your app.config